# Rails link_to with html_options is just making a url that has?html_options

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<%= link_to('Repay', controller: 'payments', 
                             action: 'repay', 
                             from: r, to: rx,
                             html_options: {class: "tiny button"}) 
                             %>
```

Rails docs say that you can pass html_options, which will be used to add attributes to the generated html, but all it's doing is adding ?html_options={class... to the url, not actually generating the link with the class.

I tried it without html_options, same thing. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I just got downvoted on a 1 and a half year old question?

Comment: Sometimes people on sf can be ridiculous

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<%= link_to('Repay', {controller: 'payments', 
    action: 'repay', 
    from: r, to: rx},
    {class: "tiny button"}) %>
```

Comment: Just to explain what is going on: ruby unpacks only one hash into arguments by default. In this case there are two hashes, and html_options is just treated as a key to the options hash without the extra brackets.